# put random number in the array list java

Tags: java, arrays, random, arraylist

I'm trying to put all random number which I generated to the arraylist and print all the random number into single array

```
    static int pick;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
        pick = rand.nextInt(100);
        al.add(pick);
        System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
        }
```

from the above function I got the result like this

```
 Contents of al: [43]
 Contents of al: [43, 44]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24, 12]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24, 12, 35]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24, 12, 35, 0]
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24, 12, 35, 0, 85]
```

the expected output I want is just the last line of the above result

```
 Contents of al: [43, 44, 3, 66, 47, 24, 12, 35, 0, 85]
```

anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Move your `System.out.println` statement to be outside of the for loop.

Comment: ok...thanks...It's working...just realize as simple as that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want print the array when it is full take the println out of the loop.

Hope that answers your question

```
    static int pick;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            pick = rand.nextInt(100);
            al.add(pick);
        }

        System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
     }
```